# Setting correct option values in Laravel

Tags: php, forms, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

can anyone help me set the option variables on a select style drop-down in Laravel 5.1?

In my controller I have

```
$buildings = Warf::select('facilityname')
    ->distinct()
    ->get();
.
.
.
return view('reports.space', compact('buildings');
```

the 'space' view looks like

```
{!! Form::open() !!}
<div class="well col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">

   <legend>Spacial Reports</legend>

            <div class="form-group">
                {!! Form::label('building_', 'Building:') !!}
                {!! Form::select('building', $buildings, null, ['class' => 'form-control'])!!}
            </div>
.
.
.

            <div class="form-group">
                {!! Form::submit('Submit', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary form-control']) !!}
            </div>

</div>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

However this results in the following HTML

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="building_">Building:</label>
    <select class="form-control" name="building"><option value="0">{"facilityname":"WARF"}</option></select>
</div>
```

Questions:
A) How can I get just "WARF" to show up in the dropdown? 
B) Is there a way to default the selection to show no values?

Thanks,
Otterman

*I am using the Collective Html generator if that makes a difference*

Comment: It might not be pretty to look at but just manually add your options with an array. I forgot which sequence it comes in the parameter but you can do array($building->ID_value = $buildings[0]->facilityname, some other data.... ). it should print out the $building[0]->facilityname and use the id_value as the value once that option is chosen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try selecting the column as "name"

```
$buildings = Warf::select('facilityname as name')
->distinct()
->get();
```

or you might need to return that using lists, something like:

```
$buildings = Warf::select('facilityname as name')
->distinct()
->lists('name','id')->all() //
```

Comment: In Laravel 5.1 it must be `->lists('name','id')->all()`

Comment: Thanks for the heads up on that!

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Is there any way to get the building name to show up in <option value="..."> so I can use it in a post method?

Comment: `lists('name','id')`, `id` is the option value, you can change to another field if you wish. If you use only `name`, it will also be the option value.